# Why Cordova is not loading the Javascipt part of the plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add the cordova-plugin-webview-proxy into my app, but for some reasons, the javascript part of the plugin is not imported into my app, on android.

The plugin branch I'm trying to install is available here: https://github.com/GEDYSIntraWare/cordova-plugin-webview-proxy/tree/android

I'm adding it into my project like this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/GEDYSIntraWare/cordova-plugin-webview-proxy/tree/android
```

Then building by cordova app with:

```
cordova build
```

In the resulting android app, in Android Studio, I can see the plugin files :
[image]

Also the cordova_plugins.js is defining it:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
  module.exports = [
    {
      "id": "cordova-plugin-geolocation.geolocation",
      "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js",
      "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
      "clobbers": [
        "navigator.geolocation"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "cordova-plugin-geolocation.PositionError",
      "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/PositionError.js",
      "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
      "runs": true
    },
    {
      "id": "cordova-plugin-webview-proxy.WebviewProxy",
      "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-webview-proxy/www/WebviewProxy.js",
      "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-webview-proxy",
      "clobbers": [
        "WebviewProxy"
      ]
    }
  ];
  module.exports.metadata = {
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-webview-proxy": "0.0.3"
  };
});
```

I can build and deploy the app from the Android Studio without any errors, but when the app starts, it will hang at the place where the plugin is supposed to be called, as the window.WebviewProxy property is not available:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'convertProxyUrl' of undefined' of undefined
    at getStr (locales.js:47)
    at callMW (mwutils.js:219)
    at mwGetLanguages (mwutils.js:251)
    at loadSettings (settings.js:9)
    at onLoad (index.html:46)
    at onload (index.html:147)
```

it fails at this line:

```
return window.WebviewProxy.convertProxyUrl(url.replace('./', BASE_URL));
```

This error was observed looking at chrome://inspect/#devices

Also, if I inspect the sources tab in the browser, I don't see any cordova .js files in there.

Any idea what is wrong?

The android app WebviewProxy.js looks like this:

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-webview-proxy.WebviewProxy", function(require, exports, module) {
/* global cordova */

function WebviewProxy() {
}

WebviewProxy.prototype.convertProxyUrl = function (path) {
    if (!path) {
        return path;
    }
    if (!window.CDV_ASSETS_URL) {
        //Android 10.x origin
        window.CDV_ASSETS_URL = location.origin
    }
    if (path.startsWith('http://')) {
        return window.CDV_ASSETS_URL + '/_http_proxy_' + encodeURIComponent(path.replace('http://', ''));
    }
    if (path.startsWith('https://')) {
        return window.CDV_ASSETS_URL + '/_https_proxy_' + encodeURIComponent(path.replace('https://', ''));
    }
    return path;
}

module.exports = new WebviewProxy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem: The issues was caused by the missing `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` from my index.html